# Having problem with MOLUSCE plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I want to simulate urban growth through MOLUSCE plugin in QGIS.

I  prepared my rasters  for two years, and a variable map by using vector format of roads and distance to road map by Euclidean distance and converted it to raster. When I add the data in molusce window the tabs are not active.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message complains that the two rasters have different geometries. According to the [QuickHelp pdf](https://github.com/nextgis/molusce/blob/master/doc/en/QuickHelp.pdf) for the MOLUSCE plugin, the geometries of the input rasters must match.

What does it mean for two rasters to have matching geometry? According to [ESRI help documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-for-georeferencing-a-raster-dataset.htm),

> "When you rectify or transform, project, or resample a raster dataset, convert it from one projection to another, or change the cell size, you are performing a geometric transformation. Geometric transformation is the process of changing the geometry of a raster dataset from one coordinate space to another."

So, make sure the two rasters have the same

- cell size
- coordinate reference system
- extent